# Combining flex direction combined with order

Tags: html, css

How to use flex to align my sections so that the footer section (4) is using the free space under section 2 without changing the div layout.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.headerEl {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    order:1;
}

.footerEl {
    background: green;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px;
    order:4;
}

.main1El {
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    order:2
}

.main2El {
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    order:3
}

header{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
}
footer{
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
}
main{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        <header>
            <div class="flex-item headerEl">1</div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="flex-item main1El">2</div>
            <div class="flex-item main2El">3</div>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="flex-item footerEl">4</div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: That can't be done with flex. Go look into grid.

Comment: custom margin-top, but this is dirty

Comment: Yes. Looking for a more responsive layout solution instead of doing tweaks with margins or relying on the the content height